# Fetch lazy object while serializing in spring data rest

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have one entity A which has some properties, and reference to another entity B

```
A{
....
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   B b;
...
}
```

same for B(@onetomany for A in B). Its a bidirectional relation.
While calling the web service for entity A it gives link to the B entity instead of whole object in response json.
I want the whole object in web service response JSON instead of link to that related entity. 
How can i do that? 
I am using springboot + spring data jpa + hibernate as jpa provider + spring 4

Comment: what is "link to the B"?

Comment: @dit : spring data rest provides url(link) for the nested objects . in this case it will provide url for B instead of object in json.

Comment: is it option to change the fetch type to FetchType.EAGER ?

Comment: @dit : i changed to eager, but still B is not included in the A's web service response.

Answer (score 7):

In order to have nested related objects in the output JSON you have to use [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts).

```
public class User {
   private String name;
   private Address address;
}

public class Address {
   private String street;
}

public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   // Custom methods
}
```

will give you

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "_links": {
      "self": "http://localhost:8080/users/1",
      "address": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
   }
}
```

BUT with projection:

```
@Projection(name = "inlineAddress", types = { User.class })
public interface UserInlineAddressProjection {
   String getName();
   Address getAddress();
}

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = UserInlineAddressProjection.class)
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   // Custom methods
}
```

result will be the following:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "address": {
       "street": "Stormtroopers str. 1"
    },
    "_links": {
       "self": "http://localhost:8080/users/1",
       "address": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
    }
}
```

This is the only way how you can implement it

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question that you are using a `Collection` on one side of the relationship (the "Many" in `OneToMany`).

There are two ways you can achieve this:

1) If you do not define a `Repository` for the child type, a link will not be generated, and it will instead be embedded in the parent object. Of course, this only is useful if you don't need a `Repository` for that object.

2) `FetchType.EAGER` will eagerly load the child object. Since the object is already loaded, there is no reason to provide a link to it, so spring-data-rest will embed the object. Make sure to put this on the side with the single object, not the `Collection`